# jquery displaying content from XML not working

Tags: jquery, html, xml, api

I cannot figure out why my code is not working.  I am grabbing job search results from a CareerBuilder API at http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHP89J6QX21LN4V61Z8&Keywords=vending&PerPage=12 and if you follow that URL you will clearly see an XML document clearly loads.  Here is some jQuery that should load results from my job search XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            $("#UpdatePanel").html("Please wait...");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHP89J6QX21LN4V61Z8&Keywords=vending&PerPage=12",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(xml) {
        var tableContent = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>" +
                            "<tr>" +
                                "<th>Company</th>" +
                                "<th>Job Title</th>" +
                                "<th>Employment Type</th>" +
                                "<th>Required Education</th>" +
                                "<th>Experience Required</th>" +
                                "<th>Job Details URL</th>" +
                            "</tr>";
        $(xml).find('JobSearchResult').each(function () {
            tableContent += "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('Company').text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('ONetFriendlyTitle').text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('EmploymentType').text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('EducationRequired').text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('ExperienceRequired').text() + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + $(this).find('JobDetailsURL').text() + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
        });
        tableContent += "</table>";
        $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent);
    }

    function OnError(data) {
        $("#UpdatePanel").html("Error! Please try again.");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btnGetData" type="button" value="Populate Data from XML File" />
<div id="UpdatePanel" style="padding:20px 10px">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using a plain Javascript method and that didn't work either.  I just can't figure out why it's just returning an error instead of results from the XML doc.  Any help would be so super appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**:

I couldn't figure this out with jQuery or JavaScript, so here's my solution using PHP:

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHP89J6QX21LN4V61Z8&Keywords=vending&PerPage=12');
for($i=0;$i<count($xml->Results->JobSearchResult);$i++){
    echo '<a href="'.$xml->Results->JobSearchResult[$i]->JobDetailsURL.'" class="job" target="_blank"><strong>'.$xml->Results->JobSearchResult[$i]->ONetFriendlyTitle.'</strong><br />'.$xml->Results->JobSearchResult[$i]->Company.'<br /><span>'.$xml->Results->JobSearchResult[$i]->City.', '.$xml->Results->JobSearchResult[$i]->State.'</span></a>';
}
?>
```

Maybe that help someone out.

Comment: what exact error does it return?

Comment: Have you tried opening up the developer toolbar in your browser and seeing what errors are being logged to your console?

Comment: When I try running your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Ldta1p2c/) i get this error: 
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.careerbuilder.com/v1/jobsearch?DeveloperKey=WDHP89J6QX21LN4V61Z8&Keywords=vending&PerPage=12. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access."
– It looks like a cross domain scripting issue to me.

Comment: Here's a codepen if anyone prefers it: http://codepen.io/dryke_chris/pen/yzCej (@JRulle posted a JSFiddle as I wrapping it up)